# Azure Devops Boards have weird style and missing avatars

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have been using Azure Devops for many years now, across multiple organizations and projects. We recently started a new project in Azure and the Sprint board looks a bit different than what I'm used to:

[image: Current organization Azure DevOps]

vs.

[image: Previous organization Azure DevOps]

as you can see the colors are a little bit different. Additionally, and more importantly, avatars are not show in the current organization. They are both using standard, unmodified Agile process with no custom templating or styles. Why is one different than the other?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem when we moved from IIRC 2012 to 2019, and the only resolution was to export and re-upload the work item templates using `witadmin`.